# How can we use SIP for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, pjsip, windows-phone-8-sdk

Downloaded `PJSIP`, but it is for `VS2008`. I am not able to use it with `Windows Phone 8.`
Is there SIP API for Windows Phone 8?

I want to develop an application that uses SIP. So does any one knows about any API that we can use for SIP in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OctroTalk](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/octrotalk-with-voip/22595f2b-8813-483f-8a62-5d17ea8b2952) - it supports both WP7 and WP8

Comment: I want to develop an application that uses SIP. So does any one knows about any API that we can use for SIP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking only for PJSIP API? As per this link http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows-Phone PJSIP does not support windows phone 8 as of now.

Answer (score 0):

PJSIP now supports Windows Phone 8. But you need some prerequisites:

- on your desktop you need Windows 8 on 64-bit
- a valid developer account for WP (it costs something)

if your PC supports virtualization you dont need a device.

Start here: http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Windows-Phone

Comment: So awesome that PJSIP now supports WP8!